# How do I detect the addition of a new monitor?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-messages

I have a windowless program that handles some window management hotkeys.  I'd like to provide features such as the ability to move a window between monitors.  I've used [`EnumDisplayMonitors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162610%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to enumerate all existing monitors in the system, and I've written code to handle `WM_DEVICECHANGE`, but I'm not actually receiving the message.

Here's my message loop:

```
// I've tried GetMessage(&msg, (HWND) NULL, 0, 0) here too
while (GetMessage(&msg, (HWND) -1, 0, 0) > 0)
{
    int key;
    int mod;

    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCWSTR) ((std::wostringstream&) (std::wostringstream() << L"You got a message: " << msg.message)).str().c_str(), L"Got Message", MB_OK);

    switch (msg.message)
    {
    case WM_HOTKEY:
        key = HIWORD(msg.lParam);
        mod = LOWORD(msg.lParam);

        if (mod != MOD_WIN) continue;
        ProcessHotkey(key);
        break;
    case WM_DEVICECHANGE:
        InitMonitorInfo();
    }
}
```

The program compiles and runs fine, and the hotkeys work.  Upon adding or removing a monitor though, nothing happens.  The message box to indicate a message has been received never appears.

I suppose I could just poll the monitor configuration every 5 seconds, but that's not the right way to solve the problem.

Do I need to actually create a window to receive `WM_DEVICECHANGE`?  Because I don't.  The hotkeys post their messages to `NULL` when they fire since they're not bound to a window, to be handled by the main thread.

Comment: Registering for device change messages: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363432(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I saw that as I was looking, do I have to pass it an actual HWND or will it accept NULL and post messages to the thread?

Comment: It sounds like a window handle may be required. When I did this I was using a hidden window. So you'll probably have to create the window, change your message loop to "GetMessage, TranslateMessage, DispatchMessage", and then handle the WM_DEVICECHANGE in your WinProc function.

Comment: You do need a window for this. You can use the styles `WS_EX_NOACTIVATE` and `WS_DISABLED` to create a window that isn't displayed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must create a window to get the [`WM_DEVICECHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363480%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message.

`WM_DEVICECHANGE` is a message that's broadcast, [`SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST,...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) style.  Only top-level windows can receive it.  The window doesn't need to be visible so there's little reason to look for an alternative.

[`RegisterDeviceNotification()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is an alternative.  But that still needs a window.  Or a service handle, but you don't want to move windows around from a service.  They run in an isolated session with their own desktop.  So creating a window is a hard requirement.